# Issue when copying two text files using the copy command

Tags: windows, cmd

I am having an issue when attempting to copy two files into a separate file using the Windows Copy command. In the first file, when I open the text file in notepad I see the data in the file formatted as expected.

File #1

```
0900|Y3RN|19944|12/OCT/2016|2|2|1600|C||||||0|0|||Replace
```

0900|Y3RN|19944|13/OCT/2016|2|2|2000|C||||||0|0|||Replace
0900|Y3RN|19944|14/OCT/2016|2|2|600|C||||||0|0|||Replace

However in the second file that has the same fields the format of the data in notepad is different.

File #2

```
0901|ECQQ|339489|18/OCT/2016|2|2|25|C||||||0|0|||Replace0901|ECQQ|339489|19/OCT/2016|2|2|180|C||||||0|0|||Replace0901|EK1P|339489|04/OCT/2016|2|2|100|C||||||0|0|||Replace
```

Supposedly the same process is generating the two files on my customer's system of record. If I open only each file separately using Textpad, the two files have the same format as File#1 above.

When I use the Copy command, the resulting file looks as below when viewing in Notepad.

```
0900|Y3RN|19944|28/OCT/2016|2|2|1400|C||||||0|0|||Replace
```

0900|Y3RN|19944|31/OCT/2016|2|2|1400|C||||||0|0|||Replace
0900|Y6CJ|19944|10/OCT/2016|2|2|200|C||||||0|0|||Replace0901|ECQQ|339489|18/OCT/2016|2|2|25|C||||||0|0|||Replace0901|ECQQ|339489|19/OCT/2016|2|2|180|C||||||0|0|||Replace0901|EK1P|339489|04/OCT/2016|2|2|100|C||||||0|0|||Replace

However when viewing the resulting file in Textpad, the format is correct.

There has to be something missing in the format of File#2, but since I do not have access or visibility to how these files are being generated my hands are tied.

Is there a way to convert File #2 so that it is formatted exactly like File#1?

Comment: The `copy` command doesn't normally change the contents of the files it copies. What's exactly is the command you're typing to copy the files?

Comment: Do some of the files come from a UNIX-like system such as Linux or MacOS? On MS-DOS-like systems such as Windows lines are expected to end with CR LF (`'\r' '\n` in C notation), while UNIX-like systems end lines with `'\n'` only. Poor Notepad is confused by such files. Use a real text editor to open the files, determine their line endings and replace them with what's usual on your platform.